# how many genesis in IoTA tangle?

Tags: iota-network, iot

If I have 10 sensors in IoT architecture and 5 of them start to send data at the same time, it will have 5 genesis in IoTA tangle? or only one genesis will be published? if so how to choose one from these 5 data, on what thing it's depends?